# Detect model format opened from importer

Tags: c++, assimp

I need to know what type of the model file is opened by Assimp via the call ReadFile(string, flags).

So, if it finds a .obj model file I want to know that somehow, is there an API in Assimp to check this?

I assume the model file does not have a file extension which makes this trivial to check (i.e model.obj is probably a .obj file).